# std::vector Struct Student example

Tags: c++, sorting, std, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct StudentDataTypes
{
    std::string name{};
    int grade{};
};

int main()
{
    //Ask for Class_Size
    int Class_Size{};
    std::cout << "How big is the class?" << '\n';
    std::cin >> Class_Size;

    //Syntax format
    //std::vector<T> array(size);
    //Intialize a vector for the students called Vector_Student
    //T links to the struct StudentDataTypes
    //size is the Class_Size.
    std::vector<StudentDataTypes> Vector_Student(Class_Size);
    
    //Print Class Size
    std::cout << "There are " << Class_Size << " students." << '\n';

    //Get the Userinputs for the Class
    for (int i = 0; i < Class_Size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Please input the name of Student #" << i + 1 << '\n';
        std::cin >> Vector_Student[i].name;
        std::cout << "Please input the grade of Student #" << i + 1 << '\n';
        std::cin >> Vector_Student[i].grade;
    }
    
    //Sort
    std::sort(Vector_Student.begin(), Vector_Student.end());

    //Print the required output
    for (int j = 0; j < Class_Size; ++j)
    {
        std::cout 
            << Vector_Student[j].name 
            << " got a grade of " 
            << Vector_Student[j].grade << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have an issue with a Vector Struct tutorial.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and there's a peculiar scenario where the compiler doesn't give me any warning at all. If I debug it, the first warning appears on line 1544, way out of bounds. The above code will actually sort of compile, run and crash.

I know the issue lies in the sorting but I can't figure it out.

Comment: How does code "sort of" compile? (It does not compile for me, which means it is not a [mre] for your crash.)

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: To sort you need a comparator function or a `<` overload that knows how to compare `StudentDataTypes`. I like the later as it's usually more intuitive.

Comment: To @jamit, it creates a console for me and it crashes at the same time.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I know the console appears for me and there's a crash at the same time.

Comment: @user4581301 Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: Could you just do a `Rebuild` (without `Run`) and show the output? I am curious how you can compile your `std::sort()` call if `StudentDataTypes` doesn't provide compare operator...

Comment: C2672
C2893
C2056
C2672
C2056
C2672
C2893
C2672
C2893
C2672
C2893
C2672
C2893
@VladFeinstein

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. 

Step 1:
bool compareTwoStudents(StudentDataTypes a, StudentDataTypes b)
{
 if (a.grade != b.grade)
  return a.grade > b.grade;
 return a.grade==b.grade;
}

Step 2:
std::sort(Vector_Student.begin(), Vector_Student.end(),compareTwoStudents);

Comment: @JonhSmithBenjamin Don't write the answer in the question. Write the answer in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` requires you to implement `operator<` for your datatype. Here in this case adding following definition in your class will get your code to compile

```
bool operator<(const StudentDataTypes& that) {
    return this->grade < that.grade;
}
```

Update:
Alternatively as sugested by Casey, we can use custom sort comparator. Here is the sample code for the same.

```
std::sort(Vector_Student.begin(), Vector_Student.end(), [](const StudentDataTypes& a, const StudentDataTypes&b) { return a.grade < b.grade; });
```

Comment: You can also provide a sort comparison argument as well, doesn't have to be part of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. I'm posting it in the answers for how to sort a vector-struct.

Step 1:

```
bool compareTwoStudents(StudentDataTypes a, StudentDataTypes b) {
    if (a.grade != b.grade)
        return a.grade > b.grade;
    return a.grade==b.grade;
}
```

Step 2:

```
std::sort(Vector_Student.begin(), Vector_Student.end(),compareTwoStudents);
```